# Silverlight application not running on safari. ERROR: Your resolution is 1024 x 768. ADplus is best viewed on resolution width 1152 or greater

Tags: c#, silverlight

The is issue is a bit confusing so please allow me to elaborate.

I have developed an application "ADplus" using silverlight 4.O.

Its running fine on MAC Book Safari browser. However, its not wroking on MAC in cloud Safari browser. I have getting an error which is given below:

[image]

> Your resolution is 1024 x 768. ADplus is best viewed on resolution
>   width 1152 or greater.

Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou so much in advance.

PS: I have just taken a Mac subscription on cloud.

Comment: The message is pretty explicit, the cloud's screen is not high enough. As *you* set the limitation, you should be able to fix it in your code...

Comment: @thomas thankyou so much for replying. Actually, it is working fine in MAC book browser. So here my purpose is to test my application on MAC browser and thats why i have taken subscription because currently i dont have any mac book. Is there no any way to make browser enough capable to run my app.    I dont want to change my code. You are asking to change resolution in my app code. Right?

Comment: You may be able to do it by zooming out on the distant browser

Comment: I am sorry but i did get what you said. Please elaborate @thomas

Comment: Try to zoom out in your browser, and then in the distant browser to see if it changes something or not